# Code refactor: CloseableHttpResponse to Resttemplate

Tags: java, spring, resttemplate, spring-resttemplate

I tried refactoring my code. After refactoring I am getting null response. Here is my older version of code:

```
import java.io.IOException;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.entity.ContentType;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class GenericRestClientImpl implements GenericRestClient {
    
    @Value("${auth.string}")
    private String authString;
    
    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(GenericRestClientImpl.class);

    @Override
    public String httpPostData(String jsonstr, String posturl) throws IOException {
            String result = "";
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(posturl);
            httpPost.setEntity(new StringEntity(jsonstr, ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON));
            httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
            httpPost.addHeader("Authorization", authString);
            System.out.println("JSON to send: " + jsonstr);
            logger.info("JSON to send: " + jsonstr);
            try (CloseableHttpClient closeableHttpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
                    CloseableHttpResponse closeableHttpResponse = closeableHttpClient.execute(httpPost);) {
                logger.info("response status code :" + closeableHttpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode());
                logger.info("response status line :" + closeableHttpResponse.getStatusLine());
                result = EntityUtils.toString(closeableHttpResponse.getEntity());
                logger.info("response data :" + result);
                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to refactor this to the Resttemplate. I have URL as String and JSON as String. How to refactor this? I tried several times but it didn't work. Is it not working because of variable type String?

Comment: Please share what you tried and what error you're getting

Comment: `@Autowired
 private RestTemplate restTemplate;

 public ResponseEntity<String> invokeService(URI uri, HttpMethod method, HttpHeaders httpHeaders,
   Optional requestBody) {
  ResponseEntity<String> response = null;
  try {
   HttpEntity<Object> request = null;
   if (requestBody.isPresent()) {
    request = new HttpEntity<Object>(requestBody.get(), httpHeaders);
   } else {
    request = new HttpEntity<Object>(httpHeaders);
   }
   response = restTemplate.exchange(uri, method, request, String.class);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 return response;
 }`

Comment: Please edit your question it's really unreadable like this @piri

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.